# Darksky api not displaying correct time

Tags: javascript, darksky

I used the Dark Sky API variable 'time' to retrieve the unix timestamp, then converted it to hour with the following code:

```
        if(navigator.geolocation){
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
                long = position.coords.longitude;
                lat = position.coords.latitude;

                const proxy = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
    const api = `${proxy}https://api.darksky.net/forecast/7fa728a1a158d84bf2c85bbeb53ddaea/36.778259,-119.417931`;

                fetch(api)
                    .then(response => {
                        return response.json();
                    })
                    .then(data => {
                        /*console.log(data);*/
                        const {temperature, summary, icon, time} = data.currently;

                                //Get date from time variable
                                var date = new Date(time*1000);
                                // Get hours from date
                                var hours = date.getHours();
                                // Get minutes from date
                                var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
                                // Get seconds from date
                                var seconds = "0" + date.getSeconds();
                                // Display time in 10:30:23 format
                                var formattedTime = hours + ':' + minutes.substr(-2) + ':' + seconds.substr(-2);

                                console.log(formattedTime);

                                //Check time
                                if (hours <= 19 && hours >= 7) {
                                //Day
                                } else {
                                //Night
                                }
});
```

Everything else is working perfectly but it's still not displaying the correct time of the retrieved location data in the console.

Comment: that is the value of time

Comment: what is the time vs the time its suppose to be?

Comment: Its supposed to show the correct time of the location where darksky api retrieves the data from. Using longitude and latitude.

Comment: what is the time expected and what is the time you get? can you tell an exmaple?

Comment: const {temperature, summary, icon, time} = data.currently;

Comment: Retrieves the data of temparature, summary and icon correctly but not time for me. It displays the current browser time instead.

Comment: because date.getHours() or date.getMinutes() etc. gets the time of the browser not Darksky

Comment: Oh I thought having the time variable in the var date uses that value.

Comment: And even if I just console log the time variable it still displays the browser time for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the docs of Dark Sky API](https://darksky.net/dev/docs) :

[The API sends a response with a specific format](https://darksky.net/dev/docs#response-format) that contains several data, but what's concerns us in this situation is:

> **timezone** *(e.g. America/New_York)* *required*
>
> The IANA timezone name for the requested location. This is used for
>   text summaries and for determining when hourly and daily data block
>   objects begin.
>
> ---
>
> ### **Data Point Object**
>
> **time** *required*
>
> The UNIX time at which this data point begins. minutely data point are
>   always aligned to the top of the minute, hourly data point objects to
>   the top of the hour, and daily data point objects to midnight of the
>   day, all according to the local time zone.

**So** the time you have read is the machine [UNIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) time and this type of time is global time it is not for a specific time zone, so if you need displaying the correct time of the retrieved location you need to convert it to Locale Time by using [**`toLocaleTimeString()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) in javascript

```js
const proxy = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
const api = `${proxy}https://api.darksky.net/forecast/7fa728a1a158d84bf2c85bbeb53ddaea/36.778259,-119.417931`;

fetch(api)
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        /*console.log(data);*/
        const { temperature, summary, icon, time } = data.currently;
        //using data.timezone to displaying correct time of the retrieved location 
        //Get  time in 24 00:00:00 format
        var formattedTime = new Date(time * 1000).toLocaleTimeString("en-US", { timeZone: data.timezone, hour12: false });
        //Get  time in 12 00:00:00 AM/PM format
        var formattedTime = new Date(time * 1000).toLocaleTimeString("en-US", { timeZone: data.timezone });
        console.log(formattedTime);
    });
```

**References :**

1. [Dark Sky API Response Format](https://darksky.net/dev/docs#response-format)
2. [The IANA timezone names](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) - [List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)
3. [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)